# Querying adjacent rows in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm working with Azure Mobile Services and have a table with GUIDs as its Primary Key (RecordId). I need to retrieve the previous and next rows of the table based on an ID.

Example of table:

```
| RecordId                             | RecordText |
|--------------------------------------|------------|
| 25892e17-80f6-415f-9c65-7395632f0223 | Hello      |
| a53e98e4-0197-4513-be6d-49836e406aaa | Bye        |
| e33898de-6302-4756-8f0c-5f6c5218e02e | Byebye     |
| 3a768eea-cbda-4926-a82d-831cb89092aa | Wow        |
```

Sample Input:
1) I enter a53e98e4-0197-4513-be6d-49836e406aaa
2) I enter e33898de-6302-4756-8f0c-5f6c5218e02e

Sample Output:
1) I'll get three results: 25892e17-80f6-415f-9c65-7395632f0223 (Previous), a53e98e4-0197-4513-be6d-49836e406aaa (Current), e33898de-6302-4756-8f0c-5f6c5218e02e (Next)

2) I'll get three results: a53e98e4-0197-4513-be6d-49836e406aaa (Previous), e33898de-6302-4756-8f0c-5f6c5218e02e (Current), 3a768eea-cbda-4926-a82d-831cb89092aa (Next)

How would I go about implementing this, and would I do this from the Node.js backend of from my ASP.NET? The use case here is a webpage where I can click Previous or Next buttons to go to the corresponding records.